# How to have a Button Change images from three different pictureboxes whilst making the previous invisible

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have 3 picture boxes added on my Visual Basic and I have one button
essentially i want the button to display the next image when its pressed and to hide the previous image (all images are set to invisible on startup)
i've tried to do stuff like
If pic1.visible then
pic2.visible = true 
pic3.visible = true
else 
pic 1 .visible = true
end if

etc etc

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific issue, and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of basing your if-statement logic on the visibility of other images, I would suggest to create a `counter` that will keep track of the active image.

To keep it simple, have the `counter` loop between 1, 2 and 3 (i.e. clicking the button 4 times would make the `counter == 1`). Then simply have your if-statement logic based on the current value of the counter.

For instance:

```
if (counter == 1) {
    pic1.show();
    pic2.hide();
    pic3.hide();
} else if (counter == 2) {
...
}
```

You can use switch statements if you'd like but I think this should give you a general idea.